# where to get sample ofx files for testing?

Tags: ofx

I am building a php application using Ofx Parser Class from  http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5778-PHP-Parse-and-extract-financial-records-from-OFX-files.html . But where can i get a sample ofx file to use this class and test my application?

Answer (score 7):

Try searching "filetype:ofx" in google. I have found a couple there. If you need a whole bunch for a more complete test I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest by far is to have an online bank account yourself that supports ofx downloads. But you're right; it's surprisingly difficult to find anything past a simplest case online.

I dug up [this article on IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-ofxv2/index.html) that includes a quick sample.  It's on parsing ofx with php and helpfully shows the difference between a well-formed XML version of an ofx and the starting-tag only version you'll often find when you download from various banks, but even this sample is only one withdrawal and one deposit.

Comment: yeah, I was surprised (although I shouldn't have been) when my bank's QFX xml only used starting tags. oy vey.

Comment: Downvotes without comments make it difficult to improve the answer to address your concerns. Let me know! I'll try my best to address it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using https://github.com/wesabe/fixofx. It has a script called fakeofx.py

> The fakeofx.py script generates real-ish-seeming OFX for testing and
>   demo purposes. You can generate a few fake OFX files using the script,
>   and upload them to Wesabe to try it out or demonstrate it without
>   showing your real account data to anyone.
>
> The script uses some real demographic data to make the fake
>   transactions it lists look real, but otherwise it isn't at all
>   sophisticated. It will randomly choose to generate a checking or
>   credit card statement and has no options.

Answer (score 1):

These are the two references I used.  The first one is about the structure of and ofx file and the second one give you the connection information for the financial institutions.

http://www.ofx.net/

http://www.ofxhome.com/